# Are longer sleeps (in C++) less precise than short ones

Tags: c++, boost, sleep

I have a task to do something every "round" minute(at xx:xx:00)
And I use something like

```
const int statisticsInterval=60;
    time_t t=0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (abs(t-time(NULL)==0))   //to avoid multiple calls in the same second that is the multiple of 60
                boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(2));//2, not 1 to make sure that 1 second passes

        t=time(NULL);
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(statisticsInterval-(t%statisticsInterval)));

        //DO WORK
    }
```

As you can see I use sleep (60sec - number of elapsed seconds in current minute). But one programmer told me that it is not precise and that i should change it to 
while loop with sleep(1) inside. I consider it highly doubtful that he is right, but I just wanted to check is somebody knows if there is less of a precision if the sleep interval is long.
I presume that sleep is implemented in a way that at certain time in the future trigger is activated and thread is put into "ready to execute thread group" so I see no reason for diff in precision. BTW OS is ubuntu and I dont care about less than 2-3 sec errors. For example if I sleep for 52 secs, 53.8 sleep is totally acceptable. 
P.S. I know about sleep defining the minimal time, and that theoretically my thread might get activated in year 2047., but I'm asking about realistic scenarios.

Comment: I agree with your gut reaction - highly doubtful.  What's his rationale?  FYI - no mention of accuracy differences based on input value in the man page: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html

Comment: What's the "while (42 > 1)" when "while (1)" will do just fine?

Comment: Code won't be reviewed so I can leave stuff like that for my amusement. :P But you are correct, for SO it is not nice, changed.

Answer (score 7):

When you do sleep(N) it tells the OS to trigger the thread at current time + N.

The reason why it isn't always accurate, is that you're not the only thread in the system.
There might be another thread that asked to be waken at that time before you, and there might just be some important OS stuff that's needed to be performed exactly at that time.

Anyway, there shouldn't be any precision issues, because the method has nothing to do with N.

The only reason that it won't be "precise" is if it's a crappy OS that can't calculate the time right. And then again, the loop won't solve that.

Comment: So I guess calling `sleep(1)` in a loop would be worse, as each call to `sleep` could have the lag.

Comment: @Node precisely.  Depending on how it is implemented, you might systematically wait longer with the loop.  Each call to `sleep` will basically involve the system getting the current tick, adding the requested number of seconds times the ticks per second to it, and causing the process to sleep until then.  Between the time you wake up, and the time you get into the system code of `sleep` again, any number of ticks may have occurred.  And since the granularity is at best one tick, the system won't count any tick that's started when you call `sleep`, so you'll lose at least 1 tick per call.

Comment: "When you do sleep(N) it tells the OS to trigger the thread at current time + N." More precisely, the OS triggers the thread no earlier than "time+N". It is allowed to trigger the thread arbitrarily late, but never early.

Comment: More precisely: It tells it to trigger at that exact time. But unfortunately, the OS might be busy at that time. So after it finishes doing its business, it checks which programs requested to be awaken since the last time it checked (if a timer signal triggered), and adds them to the work queue (according to its weighting system, and actual time request order)

Comment: The OS does sometimes try to be smart and think, "If you want me to wait 60 seconds, 65 seconds is probably ok too." Whereas with the waiting of 1 second you probably would not like 6 seconds actual delay. In short, the error might be greater absolutely, but probably much smaller relatively. The best option is a combination. Sleep(1) in a loop while constantly checking how much time is remaining to the next minute, updating current time every pass through the loop.

Comment: @Wouter Simons: No, being smart means not to preempt the process for 6 seconds in any case. So if your OS is smart, it will never do it.

Comment: @Vlad Technically I was talking about the new timer coalescing in Win7 for instance for energy savings. The tolerable delay is recommended to scale with the timer used. As he is using Ubuntu apparently, perhaps he should see what the influence of the no herz kernel option that is now common on desktops. OS's are trying to get smarter for energy efficiency. 6 second may be a slight exaggeration, but desktop OS's are far from real-time ;-)

Comment: Timer coalescing is strictly opt-in; if you don't use SetWaitableTimerEx, then you won't be subject to it. And even then the recommended intervals are _much_ shorter than 1 second; if anything doing multiple 1-second waits with coalescing would be _worse_ than a single wait.

Comment: @bdonlan you are right and I was not arguing against that. But recommendations are a bit different than you say: "To help improve system efficiency when expiring software timers that can be coalesced, we encourage you to specify both the period and the tolerable delay for the timers in multiples of 50 ms. For example, you should use timer periods of 50, 100, 250, 500, and 1,000 ms. Similarly, tolerable delay values of 50, 100, 150, and 250 ms are appropriate." See: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/C/5/9C5B2167-8017-4BAE-9FDE-D599BAC8184A/TimerCoal.docx

Comment: I don't see how this contradicts what I said - the smaller recommended tolerable delays are much smaller than 1s; you can pick as appropriate for your application.

Answer (score 7):

In some threading APIs, it's possible to be awoken *before* the sleep completes (eg, due to a signal arriving during the sleep). The correct way to handle this is to compute an absolute wake up time, then loop, sleeping for the remaining duration. I would imagine sleeping for one-second intervals to be a hack to approximate this, poorly.

However, the boost threading API's [`this_thread::sleep()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.sleep) is not documented to have these early wakeups, and so this technique is not necessary (the boost thread API does the loop for you).

Generally speaking, there are very few cases where using smaller sleep intervals improves wakeup latency significantly; the OS handles all wakeups more or less the same way. At best, you might keep the cache warm and avoid pageouts, but this would only affect the small portion of memory directly involved in the sleep loop.

Furthermore, most OSes deal with time using integer counters internally; this means that large intervals do not induce rounding errors (as you might find with floating point values). However, if *you* are using floating point for your own computation, this may be an issue. If you are currently using floating point intervals (say, a `double` of seconds since 1970), you may wish to consider integer units (say, a `long long` of milliseconds since 1970).

Comment: this_thread::sleep() is an _interruption point_, so the sleep might end prematurely. Such an interruption would take the form of an exception.

Comment: @RobH, can you explain a bit what is the importance of the  interruption point(I looked up the boost doc(http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html) and they are pretty short). I mean I really don't want to handle exceptions for a simple sleep function. :(

Comment: An interruption point is one of the tools by which you can interact with a thread. Normally you should prefer to wait on condition variables, since triggering an interruption point causes an exception to be thrown. However, condition variables have to be paired with locked mutexes, and it might just be that one loop of your thread function (and thus the time it has the mutex locked) takes longer than you'd like to wait before killing the thread. You could pop an interruption point part-way through its execution to provide an early loop exit.

Answer (score 4):

sleep is not very precise in many cases. It depends on the OS how precise. In Windows 7, timer resolution is about 15,4 ms I think. Also, you can usually tell the scheduler how to handle sleep slacking...

Here is a good read:

Linux: http://linux.die.net/man/3/nanosleep

Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx

PS: if you want higher precision on long waits, sleep some period and use the time diff based on a real-time clock. I.e. Store the current time when you start sleeping, then at each interval check how far you are from the set wait time.

Answer (score 4):

Boost.Thread implementation of sleep for POSIX systems can use different approaches to sleeping:

1. Timed waiting on mutex in case when thread is created with Boost.Thread and has a specific thread information.
2. Use `pthread_delay_np`, if available and thread is not created with Boost.Thread.
3. USe `nanosleep` if `pthread_delay_np` is not available.
4. Create a local mutex and do timed wait on it (worse case scenario if nothing else is available).

Cases number 2, 3 and 4 are implemented in a loop of 5 times (as of Boost 1.44). So if sleeping thread is interrupted (i.e. with some signal) more than 5 times - there can be a potential problem. But that is not likely to happen.

In all cases, precision will be much higher than a second, so doing multiple sleeps will not be more precise that doing a long one. You can only be concerned about your program being completely swapped out because of long sleep. For example, if machine is so busy, so kernel puts the whole program on disk. To avoid being swapped out, you have to spin (or do smaller sleeps and wake up occasionally). Usually, if performance matters a lot, programs do spin on a CPU and never call sleep, because any blocking call is to be avoided. But that is true if we are talking nano/micro-seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Sleep works in terms of scheduler time quantums (Edit: Meanwhile, the majority of operating systems supports "tickless" schedulers, i.e. there are no longer fixed quantums, however, the principle remains true... there's timer coalescing and stuff).

Unless you receive a signal there is no way you can wake up before that quantum has been used up. Also, `sleep` is not designed to be precise or accurate. Further, the time is more a guidline than a rule.

While you may think of the sleep time in terms of *"will continue after time X"*, that is not at all what's going on. Technically, `sleep` works in terms of *"mark the thread not-ready for approximately time X, then mark it ready, invoke the scheduler, and then we'll see what happens"*. Note the subtle difference between being "ready" and actually running. A thread can in principle be ready for a very long time, and never run.
Therefore, 60x `sleep(1)` can **never** be more accurate than `sleep(60)`. It will make the thread not-ready and ready again 60 times, and it will invoke the scheduler 60 times. Since the scheduler cannot run in zero time (nor can a thread be made ready in zero time, nor can you do a context switch in zero time), sleeping many times for short durations necessarily needs to take longer than sleeping once for the cumulative time, in practice.

Since you state that your OS is Ubuntu, you could as well use a timerfd[[1]](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html). Set the expire time to 1 minute and `read()` on it. If you get `EINTR`, just `read()` again. Otherwise, you know that a minute is up. Using a timer is the correct thing to do if you want precise timing (on a physical computer, it cannot be and will never be 100.00% perfect, but it will be as good as you can get, and it will avoid other systematic errors, especially with recurring events).
The POSIX `timer_create` function will work as well, it's more portable, and it may be half a microsecond or so less overhead (maybe! maybe not!) but it is not nearly as comfortable and flexible as a `timerfd`.

You cannot get more accurate and reliable than what a timer will provide. On my not particularly impressive Ubuntu machine, `timerfd`s work accurately to a microsecond no problemo. As a plus, it's elegant too... if you ever need to do something else while waiting, such as listen on a socket, you can plug the `timerfd` into the same `epoll` as the socket descriptor. You can share it between several processes too, and wake them simultaneously. Or, or,... many other things.

Answer (score 3):

In general, Sleep is not the correct method for timing of anything. Better to use a precision timer with a callback function. On Windows, one may use the "Multimedia" timers, which have a resolution no greater than 1 ms on most hardware. see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742877%28VS.85%29.aspx). When the timer expires, the OS calls callback function in close to real time. see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757767%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to sleep until a given system time (xx:xx:00), consider using the overload of  `boost::this_thread::sleep` that takes a *time*, as in `boost::posix_time::ptime`, rather than a *duration*.

for example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
int main()
{
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    ptime time = boost::get_system_time();
    std::cout << "time is " << time << '\n';
    time_duration tod = time.time_of_day();
    tod = hours(tod.hours()) + minutes(tod.minutes() + 1);
    time = ptime(time.date(), tod);
    std::cout << "sleeping to  " << time << "\n";
    boost::this_thread::sleep(time);
    std::cout << "now the time is " << boost::get_system_time() << '\n';
}
```

in C++0x these two overloads were given different names: `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` and `std::this_thread::sleep_until()`;

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl oops, had a subtle error, `microsec_clock::local_time()` does not work with boost.thread, which expects universal time. Edited to use thread's own `get_system_time()`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. It has nothing to do with C++ however. It has everything to do with the operating system.

Because of the greater focus on low power use in current portable systems, the operating systems have been getting smarter about timers.

Both [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463269) and [Linux](https://lwn.net/Articles/369361/) use timer slack in order to avoid waking up too often. This slack is automatically calculated using the timeout duration. It can be overridden in various ways if a really accurate timer is absolutely required.

What this does for the operating system is to allow it to get into really deep sleep states. If timers are going off all of the time, the CPU and RAM don't get a chance to power down. But if timers are collected together into a batch, the CPU can power up, run all of the timer operations, then power down again.

So if there are 10 programs all sleeping for 60 seconds but offset by a half-second or so, the most efficient use of the CPU is to wake up one time, run all 10 timers and then go back to sleep instead of waking up 10 times.

Comment: can you explain what does do you mean by the "CPU and RAM don't get a chance to power down" AFAIK RAM always runs at full speed.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Nope. One of the power-saving things that can be done is to reduce the clock rate of RAM.

Comment: Can you please find some reliable link on that. I tried googling it even before I posted the first comment.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: https://lwn.net/Articles/318727/ "The second component that can be optimized is memory: each memory access draws power. So what can we do about power consumption of memory? Read less often (which is essentially reclocking) or read less memory. Reducing the memory clock can save you again around 5 W"

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: That quote applies to GPU RAM but it is true for system RAM as well. I cannot find a source for it but I've been told that one thing Apple Macbooks do to get longer battery life in OSX than Windows can do is reduce RAM clocks and bus speed when it isn't needed.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Here is one about using low-power vs. high-power DRAM modes in servers. It isn't clock rate, but a very similar idea:  http://www.research.ibm.com/people/l/lefurgy/Publications/pacs2004.pdf

Comment: Oh I know about GPU RAM, "new"(for a couple gens at least) downlock RAM in 2D(before that it was only core downlock), but I thought that you have some links about the CPU RAM. Also I doubt that claim about Apple because they use Intel CPUs and I  dont think that Intel wouldnt do the same in Wintel world. :) Again it is not that important, but the thing is that I upvoted your comment and I felt bad upvoting it when I didnt know about the system RAM downlocking.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: I just double-checked, and I didn't lie at all in my answer and comments. :-) I did say, "one of the things that can be done" and in my answer I said "power down." The power down RAM modes are *definitely* implemented in real servers as you can see from the IBM paper.